# How to make `set offsets` apply to certain axis?

Tags: plot, gnuplot, offset

The gnuplot doc for [set offsets](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.2/node209.html) is extremely terse and I cannot find how offsets interact with multiple x-axes or y-axes.

I have 2 plots and they use x1y1 and x1y2, so there are 2 y-axes one on the left one on the right. Right now, when I add some top offset it applies to the plot which uses y1. How can I make it affect the plot which uses y2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what gnuplot `help offsets` says:

> Offsets provide a mechanism to put an empty boundary around the data
> inside an autoscaled graph. The offsets only affect the x1 and y1
> axes, and only in 2D plot commands.

So it looks like, it's not (directly) possible.
By the way, do you want offsets affecting...

- only y2 axis or
- y1 and y2 axes in the same way or
- y1 and y2 axes differently?

Maybe you can edit your question and add an example for illustration.

**Addition:**

Maybe the following is helpful. As you already did, you can use the `GPVAL_` variables.
Important to know, that these values are only set *after* plotting.
So, you have to plot, then modify your y1 and y2 ranges as desired and then `replot`. You could also use the variables `GPVAL_Y_MIN`, `GPVAL_Y_MAX`, `GPVAL_Y2_MIN`, and `GPVAL_Y2_MAX` which gnuplot's autoscaling algorithm suggests as ranges.

**Code:**

```
### different "offsets" for y1 and y2 axes
reset session

set xlabel "x1-axis"
set ylabel "y1-axis"
set ytics nomirror
set y2label "y2-axis"
set y2tics nomirror

plot 100*(sin(x)+1) axes x1y1 w l, \
     10*cos(x) axes x1y2 w l

Y1FromBottom = 0.40    # y1 data will use 40% space from bottom
Y2FromBottom = 0.80    # y2 data will use 80% space from bottom

set yrange[:(GPVAL_DATA_Y_MAX-GPVAL_DATA_Y_MIN)/Y1FromBottom+GPVAL_DATA_Y_MIN]
set y2range[:(GPVAL_DATA_Y2_MAX-GPVAL_DATA_Y2_MIN)/Y2FromBottom+GPVAL_DATA_Y2_MIN]

replot 
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: I wanted offsets to affect y1 and y2 differently. So the plot using y1, I want it to autoscale to the bottom 40% of the vertical space, which I did by setting a topOffset of (1-0.4)/0.4 * (GPVAL_DATA_Y_MAX - GPVAL_DATA_Y_MIN). But then I wanted ideally to also tweak the scaling of the plot using y2, which sometimes overlaps the key/legend. But it's more like a nice-to-have.

Comment: @haelix does the addition answer your question?

Comment: It gives a workaround,, but which I haven't used in my particular case. I'm accepting the answer.